# Is there a way to only allow selection for the text nodes in my nodeArray?

Tags: javascript, dom, functional-programming

I am trying to create an annotation container that wraps around a node, which uses `createTreeWalker` to find all the text nodes. I then push those into an array and now I have every single text node I could potentially apply the highlight too and the ability to annotate.

My biggest challenge right now is that it seems like you can only use these global methods with document, such as `onselectionchange` or `onslectionstart`. Which means it outputs the start and end ranges for anything i highlight on the entire document.

**I want to only allow this on text nodes that i have in my array which i mapped over.**

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react'

// Get all text nodes that Annotate wraps ✅
// Make sure the selection only works within those text nodes

const Annotate = (props) => {
  const { children, reference } = props

  const node = reference.current

  if (node) {
    let textNodes;
    let nodeArray = []
    let walk = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false)
    
    while (textNodes = walk.nextNode()) {
      nodeArray.push(textNodes)
    }

    console.log(nodeArray)

    nodeArray.map(tn => {
      let range  = new Range()
      // Setting the starting range of each textContent at 0
      range.setStart(tn, 0)
      // Setting the ending range of each textContent as the last character
      range.setEnd(tn, tn.length)

      Number.prototype.inRange = function(a, b) {
        return this >= a && this <= b
      }

      document.onselectionchange = function() {
         let {anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset} = document.getSelection();

         // Making sure selection is within some text node container?
         if (anchorOffset.inRange(range.startOffset, range.endOffset) || focusOffset.inRange(range.endOffset, range.startOffset)) {
           console.log(anchorOffset, 'start')
           console.log(focusOffset, 'end')
         }

      }
    })
  }


  return children
}

export default Annotate
```

Mutating the DOM in react is not advisable from what I've been reading but for this case it might not be entirely dumb. However, I need some help advisement here on how to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Don't use `map()` if you're not using the result. Use `forEach()` to loop over an array just for side effects.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, good call!